PING PONG ON C WITH SIGNALS
I have to code a ping pong on C with signals. I have achieved this code:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <time.h>

#define DISTANCIA_MAX 3
#define GANAR 10

static void gestion(int);
pid_t j, m;
pid_t padre;
int puntosMaq = 0, puntosJug = 0;

void actualizarArchivo(int posMaq, int posJug, int posBola, int pierde) {
    FILE* f=NULL;
    remove("fichero.txt");
    //Vamos a sobreescribir el archivo siempre, para guardar la última jugada
    if((f = fopen("fichero.txt", "w+"))==NULL){
        printf("Error durante la apertura del fichero. Cerrando programa\n");
        kill(padre, SIGTERM);
    }
    fprintf(f, "Máquina posicion: %d\nJugador posicion: %d\nBola posicion: %d\nPierde: %d\n", posMaq, posJug, posBola, pierde);
    fflush(f);
    fclose(f);
}

void leerArchivo(int *posMaq, int *posJug, int *posBola, int *pierde) {
    FILE* f=NULL;
    //Vamos a leer el archivo 
    if((f = fopen("fichero.txt", "r"))==NULL){
        printf("Error durante la apertura del fichero. Cerrando programa\n");
        kill(padre, SIGTERM);
    }
    if (posMaq != NULL && posJug != NULL && posBola != NULL && pierde != NULL) {
        fscanf(f, "Máquina posicion: %d\nJugador posicion: %d\nBola posicion: %d\nPierde: %d\n", posMaq, posJug, posBola, pierde);
    } else {
        fscanf(f, "Máquina posicion: %d\nJugador posicion: %d\n", posMaq, posJug);
    }
    fclose(f);
}

int main(){
    FILE* f=NULL;
    padre=getpid();
    int posMaq=0, posJug=0;
    int turno=0;
    
    //INICIALIZACIÓN DE RANDOM PARA QUE GENERE NÚMEROS ALEATORIOS
    srand(time(NULL));
    
    
    //GESTION DE SEÑALES
    if(signal(SIGUSR1, gestion) == SIG_ERR) printf("Error al crear el gestor\n");
    if(signal(SIGUSR2, gestion) == SIG_ERR) printf("Error al crear el gestor\n");
    
    
    
    //CREACION DE LOS HIJOS
    printf("Soy el padre con PID %d. Voy a crear a los jugadores\n", padre);
       //INICIALIZACIÓN MÁQUINA
    if((m=fork())==0){
        printf("Soy la máquina con PID %d\n", getpid());
            //Se ejecuta constantemente mientras estén jugando, esperando por señales para jugar
        for(;;) pause(); 
    }
    
       //INICILIZACIÓN JUGADOR
     else if((j=fork())==0){
        printf("Soy el jugador con PID %d\n", getpid());
         //Se ejecuta constantemente mientras estén jugando, esperando por señales para jugar
        for(;;) pause();
        
    
     }
    
    //ACCIONES DEL PADRE
    if(getpid()==padre){
        //Esperamos un poco a que se creen los hijos
        sleep(2);
        //Comienzo del juego
        printf("COMIENZA EL JUEGO!\n");
        sleep(1);
        while(puntosMaq < GANAR && puntosJug < GANAR){
            printf("====NUEVO TURNO====\n");
            printf("Soy el padre. Asignandole posiciones a máquina y jugador...\n");
            //Inicializamos posicion de la máquina
                posMaq=rand()%10;
            //Inicializamos posicion del jugador
            do{
                printf("Elija la posición del jugador(0-9): ");
                scanf("%d", &posJug);
            }while(posJug>9 || posJug<0);
            sleep(1);
            //Elección de quien comienza
            turno=rand()%2;
            if(turno){
                    //SACA LA MÁQUINA
                    printf("Turno de la máquina\n");
                    //Inicializamos la bola en la posicion de la máquina en cada turno que le toque sacar
                    actualizarArchivo(posMaq, posJug, posMaq, 0);
                    kill(m, SIGUSR1);
            }else{
                    //SACA EL JUGADOR
                    //Inicializamos la bola en la posicion del jugador en cada turno que le toque sacar
                    actualizarArchivo(posMaq, posJug, posJug, 0);
                    printf("Turno del jugador\n");
                    kill(j, SIGUSR2);
            }
            pause();
            printf("Marcador: Máquina %d - Jugador %d\n", puntosMaq, puntosJug);
            sleep(3);
        }
        if(puntosMaq==GANAR)
            printf("LA MÁQUINA HA GANADO!\n");
        else
            printf("EL JUGADOR HA GANADO!\n");
        
        kill(j, SIGUSR1);
        kill(m, SIGUSR2);
        
    }
        return(0);
    
}


static void gestion(int numero_de_senhal){
    int posMaq, posJug, posBola, pierde;
    leerArchivo(&posMaq, &posJug, &posBola, &pierde);
    sleep(1);
    printf("\n");
    printf("Estadísticas:\n");
    printf("\tMáquina posicion: %d\n\tJugador posicion: %d\n\tBola posicion: %d\n\tPierde: %d\n", posMaq, posJug, posBola, pierde);
    
    
    
    switch(numero_de_senhal){
        //LA MÁQUINA MANDA
        case SIGUSR1:
            if(getpid()==padre){
                //Si la máquina pierde, se suma un punto al jugador y se retorna al bucle del padre (main)
                if(pierde){
                    puntosJug++; 
                }
                //Si no, le toca al jugador
                else{
                    printf("Turno del jugador\n");
                    kill(j, SIGUSR2);
                    pause();
                }
            }
            else{
                //Caso 1: La máquina puede continaur
                printf("\n\tPosición Máquina: %d\n\tPosición Bola: %d\n", posMaq, posBola);
                sleep(2);
                if(abs(posBola - posMaq) <= DISTANCIA_MAX){
                    sleep(2);
                    printf("\tLa máquina(%d) puede jugar\n", getpid());
                    //Nueva posicion:
                        //Tomamos el rango de movimiento 0,1 o 2
                    int movimiento = rand() % 3;
                        //Se elige restar o sumar
                    if(rand() %2)
                        movimiento=-movimiento;
                    
                    posMaq=posMaq + movimiento;
                        //En caso de que nos pasemos de rango, se toman los extremos
                    if(posMaq < 0)
                        posMaq=0;
                    else if(posMaq >9)
                        posMaq=9;
                    //Nueva posicion de la bola:
                    posBola=rand()%10;
                    //pierde=0: sigue el juego
                    pierde=0;
                    
                    //Actualizamos el fichero
                    actualizarArchivo(posMaq, posJug, posBola, pierde);
                    //Avisamos al padre de que hemos terminado
                    kill(padre, SIGUSR1);
                //Caso 2: La máquina no puede seguir
                }else{
                    printf("\tLa máquina(%d) pierde\n", getpid());
                    //Activamos la flag de que ha perdido
                    pierde=1;
                    //Llamamos al padre para que actualice resultado
                    actualizarArchivo(posMaq, posJug, posBola, pierde);
                    kill(padre, SIGUSR1);
                }
            }
            break;
        //EL JUGADOR MANDA
        case SIGUSR2:
            if(getpid()==padre){
                //Si el jugador pierde, se suma un punto a la máquina y se retorna al bucle del padre;
                if(pierde==1)
                    puntosMaq++;
                //Si no, es el turno de la máquina
                else{
                    printf("Turno de la máquina\n");
                    kill(m, SIGUSR1);
                    pause();
                }
            }
            else{
                //Caso 1: El jugador puede seguir
                printf("\n\tPosición Jugador: %d\n\tPosición Bola: %d\n", posJug, posBola);
                if(abs(posBola - posMaq) <= DISTANCIA_MAX){
                    sleep(2);
                    printf("\tEl jugador(%d) tiene turno\n", getpid());
                    //Nueva posicion
                    int movimiento;
                    printf("Escoja cuanto se moverá el jugador (-2,-1,0,1,2)\n");
                    scanf("%d", &movimiento);
                    posJug=posJug + movimiento;
                
                        //Adecuación del rango
                    if(posJug < 0){
                            printf("\tPosición negativa: Se actualiza a 0\n");
                        posMaq=0;
                    }
                    else if(posJug >9){
                        printf("\tPosicion superior a 10: Se actualiza a 9\n");
                        posMaq=9;
                    }
                    
                    //Nueva posición de la bola
                    do{
                        printf("\tEscoge a donde tiras la bola(0-9)\n");
                        scanf("%d", &posBola);
                    }while(posBola<0 || posBola>9);
                    
                    //pierde=0: sigue el juego
                    pierde=0;
                    
                    //Actualizamos fichero
                    printf("\tNuevas estadísticas: \n\t\tPosición máquina: %d\n\t\tPosición jugador: %d\n\t\tPosición bola: %d\n\t\tPierde: %d\n", posMaq, posJug, posBola, pierde);
                    actualizarArchivo(posMaq, posJug, posBola, pierde);
                    kill(padre, SIGUSR2);
                }
                //Caso 2: El jugador no puede seguir
                else{
                    //Activamos la flag de que ha perdido
                    pierde=1;
                    //Llamamos al padre para que actualice resultado
                    actualizarArchivo(posMaq, posJug, posBola, pierde);
                    kill(padre, SIGUSR2);
                }
                    
            }
            break;
                
        
    }
}

Nevertheless, there are situations when the father ignores the signals (and, in fact, the program cant be ended with control+C). An example of execution would be this:
Soy el padre con PID 49048. Voy a crear a los jugadores
Soy la máquina con PID 49049
Soy el jugador con PID 49050
COMIENZA EL JUEGO!
====NUEVO TURNO====
Soy el padre. Asignandole posiciones a máquina y jugador...
Elija la posición del jugador(0-9): 8
Turno de la máquina

Estadísticas:
    Máquina posicion: 0
    Jugador posicion: 8
    Bola posicion: 0
    Pierde: 0

    Posición Máquina: 0
    Posición Bola: 0
    La máquina(49049) puede jugar

Estadísticas:
    Máquina posicion: 0
    Jugador posicion: 8
    Bola posicion: 2
    Pierde: 0
Turno del jugador

Estadísticas:
    Máquina posicion: 0
    Jugador posicion: 8
    Bola posicion: 2
    Pierde: 0

    Posición Jugador: 8
    Posición Bola: 2
    El jugador(49050) tiene turno
Escoja cuanto se moverá el jugador (-2,-1,0,1,2)
2
    Posicion superior a 10: Se actualiza a 9
    Escoge a donde tiras la bola(0-9)
8
    Nuevas estadísticas: 
        Posición máquina: 9
        Posición jugador: 10
        Posición bola: 8
        Pierde: 0

Estadísticas:
    Máquina posicion: 9
    Jugador posicion: 10
    Bola posicion: 8
    Pierde: 0
Turno de la máquina

Estadísticas:
    Máquina posicion: 9
    Jugador posicion: 10
    Bola posicion: 8
    Pierde: 0

    Posición Máquina: 9
    Posición Bola: 8
    La máquina(49049) puede jugar

I would like to know why the father ignores the signal of its children, and how to fix it.

Don't SHOUT AT US in the title, then English is the language of the site so translate what is in the question.

Signals are not a very reliable IPC mechanism. Signals are not queued, so if a signal is received twice before it's handled, one of them will be ignored.

Please rewrite the question as a [mre], with English comments/variable names/ printed statements.  Then show us exactly how it fails, and what processes are running when the parent is allegedly unresponsive.  (It's possible, e.g., that the parent process is dead when you say it is immune to Ctrl-C.) Then be prepared to be told to stop using signal, and to use only async-signal-safe functions in a signal handler.
